# Chern classes and almost complex submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, almost-complex

Suppose $M$ is a manifold endowes with an almost complex structure, such that the Chern classes $c_i(M)$ of $M$ are defined. Can we say that the Poincare dual to $c_i(M)$ can be represented by an almost complex submanifold of $M$?

Comment: You mean *can be represented by* such a submanifold? There are non-smoothable Schubert varieties in Grassmannian. For example, $c_2(F)$, where $F$ is the tautological quotient bundle on $G(2,5)$ cannot be represented by a nonsingular subvariety. See [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/reviserigidity.pdf). For the tautological subbundle $E$ on the Grassmannian $G(k,n)$, the usual Schubert variety to which $c_1(E)$ is dual is singular, but it is homologous to a smooth subvariety.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I will change it.